# examples of Chow rings of surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, chow-groups, examples

Can somone provide me (articles/literature) with examples of Chow rings of surfaces?

(e.g. here: http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/huybrech/K3Global.pdf Chapter 9)

What I want is a list of (smooth projective surface $X/\mathbf{F}_q$, $CH^*(X)=CH^0(X)⊕CH^1(X)⊕CH^2(X)$, the product structure on this, $\mathrm{deg}: CH^2(X) \to \mathbf{Z}$ and the ample cone).

Answer (score 4):

For rational surfaces, there is the paper by Colliot-Thélène [Hilbert's Theorem 90 for K2, with Application to the Chow Groups of Rational Surfaces](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN356556735_0071&DMDID=DMDLOG_0007).

For K3 surfaces, there is the paper by Beauville and Voisin [On the Chow ring of a K3 surface](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=on%20the%20chow%20ring&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CFsQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.unice.fr%2F~beauvill%2Fpubs%2Fbv.pdf&ei=mi7fT-ekIeGp4gTfmqiuCg&usg=AFQjCNGoU3v4em-jfr2j_AIa7vmLlf4HBA&cad=rja).